Video tag with MDX giving Minified React error #418
I am creating some documentation, writing pages in MDX which are processed using the rspress.js static site generator.  All works well except for an embedded short video, which displays on my local version (on localhost), but does not display when the site is uploaded to my server.  Chrome DevTools shows an error  Minified React error #418, which translates to "Hydration failed because the server rendered HTML didn't match the client. As a result this tree will be regenerated on the client.".  Although React suggests some possible sources of this error, neither this nor Google has helped me identify the problem.
The MDX code is:
* **New link** (or edge). Click on the arrow button and then drag from one factor to another to link them. If you wish, you can have two links between a pair of factors: one for each direction.

    <video width={640} height={360} muted loop autoPlay playsInline>
      <source src={normalizeImagePath("/images/create-link-nodes.mp4")} type="video/mp4" />
    </video>

(normalizedImagePath is a rspress function that sets up the correct path to the video; it is also used with <img>s in the same file, and these display, so it is not likely to be the path setting that is causing the error).
The corresponding HTML that my browser sees is:
<li class="[&amp;:not(:first-child)]:mt-2">
<p class="my-4 leading-7"><strong class="font-semibold">New link</strong> (or edge). Click on the arrow button and then drag from one factor to another to link them. If you wish, you can have two links between a pair of factors: one for each direction.</p>
<video width="640" height="360" muted="" loop="" autoplay="" playsinline=""><source src="/doc/help/doc_build/images/create-link-nodes.mp4" type="video/mp4"/></video>
</li> 

What am I doing wrong?

Referring to the documentation of Vercel, try removing the autoplay from video tag. It can cause differences between the server-side rendered HTML and the client-side HTML.

Thanks for the suggestion.  However, I removed autoPlay but it did not make a difference - still no visible video, and still React error#418.
